# Inject / Provide with typescript in vue3 : Property '?' does not exist on type '{ error: any; loading: any; interactions: any; } | undefined'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to use a child component to separate the display of some stuff (the async result of a db query).
I tried provide/inject system from Vue to pass variables between the components.
It works but still the child component seems to complain.
This is a subset of the code to give an idea.

In my parent component:

```html
<template>
  <InteractionResults /> <!-- the child -->
</template>  

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, provide } from 'vue';

const loading = ref<boolean>(false);
const error = ref<boolean>(false);
    
let interactions = ref<Interaction[]>([]);
    
provide('search', { error, loading, interactions })
</script>
```

In my child component (`InteractionResults`):

```html
<template>
  <h6>interactionResults</h6>
  {{loading}} 
<template> 

<script setup lang="ts">
import { inject } from 'vue';
import type { Interaction } from '@/models/Interaction'; 

const { error, loading, interactions } = inject('search');
// It complains and the 3 variables are highlighted in red.
</script>
```

The code is working but VS Code complains as follows (`interactions` for example, but the two other variables give the same error with their respective names):

> Property 'interactions' does not exist on type '{ error: any; loading: any; interactions: any; } | undefined'.ts(2339)

Comment: `inject` cannot guarantee that that the value for a key was ever `provide`-ed, so the return type includes a union with `undefined`. `undefined` obviously has no properties, resulting in the error given by TypeScript.

Comment: See the [types and explanation in the docs for `inject()`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#inject).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand very well the doc from the link you provided.It would be nice if you could provide an example what the code should be for "loading" for example and also in the case or a ref(). I tried to add a default value for "loading" in the inject part without success.

Comment: While I _do_ recommend learning how to use `provide`/`inject`, is this the best method for this case? Based on the code you've given, I would say that a prop (or props) on the child component would be better.

Comment: You are using an object, so you would need a default for the entire object. Something like `{ error: undefined, loading: false, interactions: [] }`. See also [the docs on typing `provide`/`inject`](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-provide-inject) for how to use them properly and safely with TypeScript.

Comment: As to what the code should be for `loading`, you would need to get the injected object without destructuring it, and check if it is `undefined` or not. Then you can either destructure that or access properties on it directly.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.I Tried to define values as you suggest but didn't make it. You lost me with the destructuring part.It's a child with its grand parents, it's a reason why I didn't use props in first instance. I can remodel a little bit to try props, what it would look like ? Yeah ok read the doc ,got it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-provide-inject):

> When using string injection keys, the type of the injected value will be `unknown`, and needs to be explicitly declared via a generic type argument:
>
> ```
> const foo = inject<string>('foo') // type: string | undefined
> ```
>
> Notice the injected value can still be `undefined`, because there is no guarantee that a provider will provide this value at runtime.

---

In your specific case, it means you have to specify the type explicitly as a type argument for `inject` and also provide a default value, which would be used in the case in which the provider does not provide a value at runtime:

```
import { inject } from "vue"
import type { Interaction } from "@/models/Interaction"

interface SearchInterface {
  error: unknown
  loading: boolean
  interactions: Interaction[]
}
const defaultSearch: SearchInterface = {
  error: null,
  loading: false,
  interactions: []
}
const { error, loading, interactions } =
  inject<SearchInterface>("search") || defaultSearch
```

Without the default value, TS will object, since `undefined` cannot be destructured.

---

If you need to do the above in multiple places, it might make sense to place the interface declaration and default value into a separate file and import them from there, to keep your code DRY.